# Is $f(x) = e^x$ one-to-one if $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functions, inverse

My book says that $f(x) = e^x$ is not invertible from the set of real numbers to the set of real numbers. But I disagree since $f(x) = e^x$ is injective with this given domain and codomain and therefore invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f: \mathbb R\to (0,\infty)$, defined as $f(x)=e^x$ is bijective. there exists an inverse function $f^{-1}:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ for which we have $$f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)

However, $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, defined as $g(x)=e^x$ is **not** bijective, because there is no $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $g(x)=-1$.

Comment: A a function has an inverse if and only if it is one-to-one (injective), right?

Comment: @user19405892 Wrong, Bijective.

Comment: My book says that if a function is invertible if it is a one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: @user19405892 However, it **is** true that if $f:A\to B$ is injective, then $f: A\to f(A)$ is **bijective**

Comment: One-to-one correspondence is defined to mean one-to-one _and_ onto.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for clearing up that confusion.

Comment: I do think this is tricky to get over once you have learned the college algebra definition of one-to-one or invertible... @user19405892

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=e^x$, with $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, is injective but not surjective since $e^x>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

To turn an injective function into a bijective (hence invertible) function, it suffices to replace its codomain by its actual range. In this particular case that means defining the function as $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R_{++}.$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the author has in mind that $\exp : \mathbb R \to (0,\infty)$ is invertible but $\exp : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is not, since not every member of $\mathbb R$ has an image under the inverse function.  You might want to look with a fairly high-resolution microscope at how this particular author defines things.